# Other users checkouts are not visible in Source Control Explorer (TFS Express)

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Other users checkouts are not visible in Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio 2012, TFS is express edition :

[image: check outs not visible]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TFS 2012 introduces a new concept called *local workspaces*, which differ subtly from the behavior of workspaces in previous versions of TFS (the old default behavior is now called a *server workspace*.)

With a local workspace, TFS behaves like an edit/merge/commit-type version control system.  That is to say that files are not read-only and instead TFS will scan your filesystem to determine what has been changed.  You no longer need to check files out from the server and, in fact, the server does not know what you have checked out.

For this reason, you will not be able to see that the other user has checked out the file - this information exists only in his or her local workspace.

If this other user was using a traditional *server workspace*, the server would have this information and would present it to you.

Comment: yes, I noticed that files are not read only anymore. I changed workspace location to server for all users and I can see all checkouted files :)

Comment: there are differences from server workspaces and local workspaces which should be considered before "hitting the switch". We're currently working through the change in policy, and while the "Server Workspace" solves the "visibility" issue, it limits other functionality such as not being able to work offline.

Comment: Is there a command line query(TFS power tolls based) to list all local workspaces?  This way or any other way, how to detect all local workspaces?