# TFS 2012 query all checked out files

Tags: visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Other users checkouts are not visible in Source Control Explorer (TFS Express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621607/other-users-checkouts-are-not-visible-in-source-control-explorer-tfs-express)

For TFS 2010 I used Team Foundation SideKicks to check if someone in our team had files checked out.

In TFS2012 Team Foundation Sidekicks does not work anymore.

So i'm trying to figure out how to see if someone (anyone) has checked out files.
So I checked some files out myself, to test things.

**First**: In VS2012 > Source Control Explorer > Rightmouse on $\ (top root node) > Find > Find By Status > Path": $/, Wildcard left empy > Checked Recursive > Checked Status > Checked Display all checked out. > Find button.

Result: nonthing!!! No items found. HUH???????? How is this possible. I have checked out files, if i browse to that node, i see checked out files. What is going on here????????

Is this a bug???

**Second**: Command line:

```
tf.exe status $/ /s:http://[server]:8080/tfs /recursive
```

Message:

```
Changes from local workspaces will not be displayed when using the /user option
if a workspace is not supplied or if that workspace is on another machine.
There are no pending changes.
```

I think this is because we are using Local workspaces? 
I want to still use local workspaces.

But how do i check if someone has files checked out?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the problem....

When you edit your workspace in vs2012, in the advanced view (click advanced button when editing your workspace), there is a property called 'Location'. This was set to 'Local'. When we set it to 'Server', all queries described above did work again.

Seems that this is a new feature in TFS2012/VS2012. And in the TFS2010/VS2010 age, the default was simular to 'Server'.

Problem solved....

Comment: This isn't a solution, and you really should look into working with local workspaces. You'll probably find that you like them. Also, with local workspaces (which didn't exist in TFS prior to 2012), files are not check-out until they are being edited. But this has no effect on your ability to work on the file, since you have your own copy on your own workspace. Go [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/11/30/team-foundation-server-trying-to-understand-server-versus-local-workspaces.aspx) for more.