# vs.net 2012 tfs how to select all checkout files for a user?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

how can I select all the checkout files for a user in tfs 2012? When looking in the source control explorer in can see the find changesets but not a status option?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Other users checkouts are not visible in Source Control Explorer (TFS Express)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621607/other-users-checkouts-are-not-visible-in-source-control-explorer-tfs-express)

Comment: this is a different question I just want a list of all the checkoutfiles for a user

Comment: Is that user using a local workspace?  If so, I suggest that this is a duplicate.  More details in your question would help us answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the commandline:

```
 tf status $/Project/ /collection:http://yourtfsserver:8080/tfs/YourCollectionName
```

From Team Explorer the option isn't there by default, but the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f) add this feature to the context menu:

> Team Explorer Enhancements
>
> This tool provides additional Visual Studio menu options and functions
>   to support **finding files under version control by status or wildcard**,
>   opening a folder using File Explorer from the Source Control Explorer
>   context menu, and labeling files and folders in Source Control
>   Explorer.  Clone builds definitions easily and copy work item paths.
>   Collaborate and share with your teammates within Visual Studio using
>   the new Team Members page in the Team Explorer tool window. You can
>   communicate with your team through instant messaging, share queries
>   and components, create workspace templates, and track your sprint
>   progress.