# How to query all the files checked out by a user in Visual Studio 2012 TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfvc

This question is not a duplicate of [Other users checkouts are not visible in Source Control Explorer (TFS Express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621607/other-users-checkouts-are-not-visible-in-source-control-explorer-tfs-express)

In contrast to [Other users checkouts are not visible in Source Control Explorer (TFS Express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621607/other-users-checkouts-are-not-visible-in-source-control-explorer-tfs-express) , **I can see** who has checked out a specific file in Source Control Explorer.

What I want to have is a way to query where I enter the **username**, and get **a list of files he or she has checked out**.

This [used to be possible in VS2010](http://adamprescott.net/2012/09/11/see-what-other-users-have-checked-out-in-tfs/). However, I don't seem to find the equivalent dialog in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: If your users are using local workspaces then I don't believe you can get a list of files.  If you absolutely must get then then make people switch to server workspaces.

Comment: @Betty We don't use local workspaces. We use server workspaces.

Comment: @Edward Thomson Can you remove the Duplicate tag and reopen the question as I have explained in detail, why this isn't the case.

Comment: Even with local workspaces, checkouts are synced to the server in the background.

Comment: @jessehouwing I'm really interested in exploring the ability to sync local workspace checkouts to the server, do you have a reference for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it from the commandline, using `tf.exe status`

```
Microsoft (R) TF - Team Foundation Version Control Tool, Version 11.0.60315.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Displays information about pending changes to items in one or more workspaces.

tf status [itemspec] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
          [/login:username,[password]]
          ([/workspace:workspacename[;workspaceowner]]
          | [/shelveset:shelvesetname[;shelvesetowner]])
          [/format:(brief|detailed)] [/recursive] [/user:(*|username)]
          [/nodetect]
```

Or using the [Team foundation Server Power Tools for Visual Studio 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f).

> Team Explorer Enhancements
>
> This tool provides additional Visual Studio menu options and functions
>   to support **finding files under version control by status or wildcard,
>   opening a folder using File Explorer from the Source Control Explorer
>   context menu**, and labeling files and folders in Source Control
>   Explorer.  Clone builds definitions easily and copy work item paths.
>   Collaborate and share with your teammates within Visual Studio using
>   the new Team Members page in the Team Explorer tool window. You can
>   communicate with your team through instant messaging, share queries
>   and components, create workspace templates, and track your sprint
>   progress.

Comment: Both of the solutions you suggest work for me. tf.exe status with /user:(*|username) does a good job. I prefer Team Explorer Enhancements though as its output is better structured and more readable. I'm glad it is still possible to exchange information in StackOverflow.

Comment: i cannot find out tf.exe file

Comment: Try opening a visual studio developer command prompt or use vswhere https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere/issues/136