# Using TFS power tools 2013 to query checked out files in Visual Studio 2013 return nothing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs-power-tools, vcs-checkout

I was trying to find all checked out files from TFS using TFS power tools 2013 add-in in Visual Studio 2013. But the search results are always empty.

The TFS server is 2012 though. See the following screenshot I took for testing.

I checked out few files, then search the same folder, but nothing show up.Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of the IDE do you have? Just checking since there is a dependency on VS Pro and up.

Comment: Thanks Lukkha, the VS2013 we used is VS K13 Premium with Update. I have put a detail screenshot with my original post. Please let me know if you need any other info. BTY, could you give me some idea, if there is some dependency, how can I fix or enable it?

Comment: Hi Lukkha, I found a post "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621607/other-users-checkouts-are-not-visible-in-source-control-explorer-tfs-express" which mentioned the issue was caused by "local workspace" instead of "server workspace", is that true? Do you know how to switch to "server workspace" from "local workspace"?