# Team Foundation Server check-out not showing for team mates

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Came across a small issue. Working with TFS VS 2012. The issue relates to seeing Check-out. Basically, if someone from my team check-out a file from TFS, I am able to see that they've checked it out -- under `Pending Change`
, and `USER` However, If I check something out, they aren't able to see it.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: Where are they looking to see it? Source control explorer is the reliable place, but the glyphs next to file names in the Solution Explorer have always seemed less reliable.

Comment: @StingyJack in the window under LOCAL PATH.

Comment: Are your workspaces Local or Server? http://stackoverflow.com/q/12621607/16391

Comment: @StingyJack - LOCAL - please see Image in question, that's where it show it correctly on my machine vs my coworkers. It doesnt show it to them when I have stuff checked out

Comment: If you are using a Local workspace (not the same as "LOCAL PATH"), then only your workspace knows about the changes.

Comment: @StingyJack - yeah it seems like this is the issue, but I still wonder why i can see if someone else has checked out a file

Comment: Because they are using a Server workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@StingyJack is correct. Pending changes of team members who use local workspaces are not visible to other team members in Source Control Explorer. It seems you are using local workspace, while other team members are using server workspace.

You can read more about Local Workspace and Server Workspace at website below:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace